# Oracle-apex dynamic list of values

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to make a select list in apex in which when i select any number from select list then it displays diffrent column table for example when i select 1 then it display (bags) when select 2 it displays (trousers)...

Comment: Okay. Are we talking 2 **page item** select lists here?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question right.

For a select list you need to create a list of values. There you have to fill two columns, the Display Value Column and the Return Value Column.

Like the label says, the Display Column is for displaying (like trousers, bags) and the return value returns another value (like 2, 1) to the database. On the database it won't be saved as trousers or bags, it will be saved as 2 and 1.

Hope this helped you.